# Make circle when user touch

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics

When the user clicks the screen a circle should be drawn where the user touch. Whats wrong with my code?

```
{
    BOOL _touchHasBegun;
    CGPoint whereUserClicked;
    float pointWhereUserClickedX;
    float pointWhereUserClickedY;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _touchHasBegun = YES;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 1);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(pointWhereUserClickedX, pointWhereUserClickedY, 10, 10);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to call `setNeedsDisplay` to force `drawRect:` to be called.  This can be done from your touch event handlers.

Secondly, you aren't drawing the circle *around* the touch point, but rather you are using the touch point as the corner of the circle.

This should correct that:

```
const CGFloat width = 10.0;
const CGFloat height = 10.0;
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(pointWhereUserClickedX - (width / 2.0),
                              pointWhereUserClickedY + (height / 2.0),
                              width,
                              height);
```